# Using OAuth2.0 library in Java to call Fitbit API

Tags: java, http, oauth-2.0, fitbit

I would like to access users' data of the fitbit by using fitbit API

what I understood is,
1- I have to get users consent by OAuth 2.0 authentication.
2- Get the access token.
3- Then can request the data by using the token.

I have downloaded the OAuth 2.0 Library from this link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadoauth2jar.htm

I have read the fitbit API documentation and I have fill the request by the parameter described in the doc as the following example

https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=22942C&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffitbit_auth&scope=activity%20nutrition%20heartrate%20location%20nutrition%20profile%20settings%20sleep%20social%20weight&expires_in=604800

The question is how to do this requests in my java app? what is the missing I have to install it to able make a http request from the java.

Also, where and how I can use the OAuth 2.0 lib if the http request will be done by Java

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Google OAuth Java client](https://github.com/google/google-oauth-java-client/tree/master).  There is a sample of how to use the client [available here](https://github.com/google/google-oauth-java-client/blob/master/samples/dailymotion-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/dailymotion/cmdline/DailyMotionSample.java).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now when I use URL connection I can request and get the response from the server , what is the benefit of using OAuth 2.0 lib ?? Where I can use it if the authentication has been done by the http requests and responses using URL Connection ....

Comment: You're not required to use an OAuth library, but it can help with implementing the OAuth flow.  It's recommended to use an OAuth library on Fitbit's website: https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/